# How to convert .wav to .mp3 file in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, mp3, wav, converters

I am currently developing a website using the CodeIgniter framework and in one of the Process I need to download a .wav music file and convert it to .mp3 file.
All the coding needs to be done only in PHP and I cannot use Ruby or java to do so.

And I am currently hosting on a shared env i.e. Dreamhost.

So please let me know how to work out this problem.

Comment: Can you at least call command line?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, but you can certainly implement one, if you *really* wanted to.  <meta>Welcome back by the way.  :-D  Happy to see that your leave of absence is over.</meta>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).  There is a [PHP extension for it](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/), but I've found better success just calling `exec()`.  Most hosts I have used (even shared hosting) will install it if it isn't already available.

**Edit:** Dreamhost provides this for you.  See this:  http://wiki.dreamhost.com/FFmpeg

And this:  http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Php-ffmpeg

Comment: I would recommend using [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/), for the simple reason that LAME is generally accepted as the best quality encoder available (There are **large** differences between the various encoders).

Comment: @Khalid Before you deface an answer again, consider reading the question.  The person specifically asked about Dreamhost which is why I mentioned it.  I'm not advertising for Dreamhost... I wouldn't *dream* (ha!) of doing such a thing.

Comment: @Brad, next time I should take more time before an action. my apologies!