# Wav to Ogg or MP3 in PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg, wav, ogg

Is there any solution for converting Wav to Ogg or MP3 by using pure PHP?
Technically it's possible. But what about ready-made libraries?

Im talking about 1-7 sec wav.

Comment: None that I am familiar with. PHP wasn't really made for this. I usually do this type of stuff by sending it off to another program written in a different language.

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330486/how-to-convert-wav-to-mp3-file-in-php)

Comment: Unfortunally i havent access to server that i could install ffmpeg or something other. Maybe is there some algorithm of converting wav to ogg that could be implemented in PHP by for example me :d?

Comment: @KamilKrzyszczuk Surely your time could be spent wiser than to attempt wav conversion by yourself :)

Comment: I'd really really recommend against attempting this.  While it may be theoretically possible, the code would be extremely complicated, and PHP would run it really slowly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing this in pure PHP will melt your brain for sure. That said, you can create a PHP extension wrapper around ffmpeg if you know enough C. That would probably be the most optimal.

Alternatively, you can just use `exec()` unless you want to distribute your code and hate to have this as a (reasonable) dependency.

In both cases you would need to have a working ffmpeg library installed on the server.

**Disclaimer**

I didn't read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330486/how-to-convert-wav-to-mp3-file-in-php) before writing my own :)