# Compress wav file to a small m4a or mp3 file by using AS3/PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, mp3, wav, m4a

Is it possible to compress a wav file to a small m4a or mp3 file by using AS3 OR PHP?

Comment: Something to check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330486/how-to-convert-wav-to-mp3-file-in-php

Answer (score 1):

To save server traffic and cpu You shold compress it on user PC using as3 , here is library I use :
https://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg on your server to do that!

You will find a [PHP-Extension for the ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) at Sourceforge.

Download [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) at the project website.