# Audio player to play wav files in all browsers?

Tags: wav, audio-player

I am looking for audio player to play wav audio file.

Html 5 audio tag does not work with internet explorer.

Jwplayer doesnot support it.

I have only wav files and more than 400 and will increase in future.

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't covert wav to mp3?? And than use jwplayer - that would be your solution.

Comment: @Saint thanks for reply. is it the only solution. will jwplayer play mp3 in ie6, 7 and 8?

Comment: Jwplayer is only supported by:

Chrome 
Firefox  
Internet Explorer 8
Internet Explorer 9 
Opera 
Safari

Comment: You can convert the files on the fly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330486/how-to-convert-wav-to-mp3-file-in-php

Comment: For the record, conversion to mp3 is your best solution...

Comment: @ceving is it free to convert from wav to mp3.

Comment: try this - an online wav to mp3 converter ... http://audioformat.com/wav-to-mp3

Comment: @RahulTailwal Lame uses the [LGPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html).

Comment: so why is wav there is we have to go with old mp3 again.

Comment: is there any way to play mp3 audio file on a button click. I have this jwplayer files. http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/trunk/fl5